# How can I parse stringified JSON in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the section "field" as list but I can only get that as String.

```
String response = "{
         "key": "Success",
         "value": {
        "fieldConfigId": 1,
        "field": "[{\"FieldId\":3,\"FieldName\":\"textbox\",\"FieldElementType\":\"textbox\",\"FieldLabel\":\"phone\",\"Discription\":\"input your number here\",\"IsDeleted\":false,\"CreatedDateUTC\":\"2021-08-01T07:23:34.963\"},{\"FieldId\":1,\"FieldName\":\"numeric\",\"FieldElementType\":\"number\",\"FieldLabel\":\"phone\",\"Discription\":\"input your number here\",\"IsDeleted\":false,\"CreatedDateUTC\":\"2021-08-01T07:23:34.963\"}]"}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:
‍‍‍

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(Your Data);
Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(data['value']);
List<Map<String, dynamic>> field = json.decode(value('field');
```

check it out and let me know the result.